# How to make case insensetive searcn in Django with Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search, django-rest-framework

I have a project with Django, Django REST Framework and PostgreSQL.
And my goal to make a search with certain conditions:

- logical operators (AND, OR, NOT)
- case insensitive
- operator like `*` To search by prefixes. som* -> search for some, somali and so on

My first attempt was to use Postgres full search with this type
`search_type='websearch'`

It's all good but don't have operator `*`
So I switched to raw type search and my class for search looks like it now

```
class DataSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.query_params.get('query')
        
        if q:
            vector = SearchVector('research', 'data', 'research__name')
            query = SearchQuery(q, search_type='raw')
            queryset = Data.objects.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
        else:
            queryset = Data.objects.none()
        return queryset
```

Logical operator works, search by prefixes works with `:*` but I don't know how to make it case insensitive.

Is it possible to make this type of search case insensitive? Or maybe there are another option for it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

SearchQuery(q, search_type='raw', config='english')

OR

SearchQuery(q, config='pg_catalog.simple', search_type='raw')

Answer (score 0):

This article contains more details about search in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/